# jsp dropdown not auto-selecting correct value

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a mostly auto-populated drop-down list on a jsp page. When the form is submitted the search results get displayed in a table below when the page reloads, and all the drop-down's and other field entries are repopulated as they were before the submit.

Except this one value `<option value="A"><spring:message code="code.label.ANE" /></option>`. Its not like the others. It wasn't dynamically created from the database because its basically just multiple results rolled into one and thus isn't a valid database code. The others will correctly get re-selected, but not this one.

I assume that `<option value="">${Select}</option>` only works because its the first value and thus gets selected by default. Cant actually test it because that value doesn't support any searches.

No, my value cant become the new default because its unlikely to be the only custom report option.

```java
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>
            <spring:message code="common.label.lifeCycle" />
        </label>
        <form:select path="hrmsLifeCycleCode" id="hrmsLifeCycleCode" cssClass="form-control">
            <spring:message code="field.select" var="Select" />
            <option value="">${Select}</option>
            <option value="A"><spring:message code="code.label.ANE" /></option>
            <form:options items="${hrmsLifeCycle}" itemValue="codeValue" itemLabel="longDesc" />
        </form:select>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the jsp add the following

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        <c:if test="${querySelect == 'A'}">
            $("#hrmsLifeCycleCode").val('A'); 
        </c:if>
    });
```

in the controller

```java
    model.addAttribute("querySelect", hrmsLifeCycle.getHrmsLifeCycleCode());
```

As the controller is now passing the selected value, when the selected value is this one case thats not being auto-selected it will select it after the page has been loaded.

This isnt the best solution but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better solution that does not require a change to the jsp. While the original fix was minimal, this one is better but slightly more involved.

As the controller has two sections for this, the normal page, and one where the form/search has been performed, both sections needed to be altered.

So the original statement which produces the attribute was

```java
   model.addAttribute("hrmsLifeCycle", GeneralCodeManager.getInstance().getList(GeneralCodeManager.LIFECYCLE_PROC_DESC_CTBL_HRMS_ONLY));
```

is instead changed to

```java
    List<GeneralCode> something = new ArrayList<GeneralCode>(); 
    GeneralCode newCode = new GeneralCode(-1, STRING_NEW_REPORT_ID, "-1", "Report Name");
    something.add(newCode);
    List<GeneralCode> extraList = GeneralCodeManager.getInstance().getList(Report_ID);
    extraList.add(something);
    model.addAttribute("hrmsLifeCycle", extraList);
```

So the above creates a new list element for the report and adds it.

This can further be improved by something I learned about a week or two ago, and thats defining modelAttributes in the controller outside of the requestMapping.

```java
    @ModelAttribute("hrmsLifeCycle")
    List<GeneralCode> something = new ArrayList<GeneralCode>(); 
    GeneralCode newCode = new GeneralCode(-1, STRING_NEW_REPORT_ID, "-1", "Report Name");
    something.add(newCode);
    List<GeneralCode> extraList = GeneralCodeManager.getInstance().getList(Report_ID);
    extraList.add(something);

    return extraList;
    }
```

and to access would use

```
    "${extraList}"
```

And to really improve it, better names would help, lol.